# Grep search files using a list of keywords

Tags: grep

I've build this command up from searching questions here. It works if I supply the keyword manually, e.g.

```
while read line; do grep -wFrIin "keyword" --exclude-dir={.git,target} --include=\*.{java,ts,html} /path/to/project/; done < keywords.csv
```

But if I'm using the actual content of the keywords file then I get no results:

```
while read line; do grep -wFrIin "$line" --exclude-dir={.git,target} --include=\*.{java,ts,html} /path/to/project/; done < keywords.csv
```

Also, when I echo out the $line I get the keywords:

```
while read line; do echo "$line"; done < keywords.csv
```

I throught it might be a \r\n or \n issue but it still doesn't work if there is only one keyword in the file with no newline...

Comment: `grep` has `-f` function to read from file. Please give some example input of your files and expected output.

Comment: @pLumo Thank you, that worked, I've changed it to `grep -FrIin -f keywords.csv --exclude-dir={.git,target} --include=\*.{java,ts,html} /path/to/project/` but the loop still don't work